# VNC desktop freezes when I try to change screen resolution

Tags: remote-desktop, resolution, gnome, mobaxterm, tigervnc

I'm using MobaXterm to connect to a remote Ubuntu 22.04 GNOME GUI desktop through VNC. The VNC server is started with the following command:

```
vncserver -localhost no -geometry 3840x2160 :5
```

The VNC desktop works fine until I try to change screen resolution in the Display Settings dialog of GNOME. When I tried to change the resolution to 1920x1200, say, by selecting this new resolution and clicking the blue "Apply" button at the up-right corner of dialog, the GNOME GUI desktop contained in VNC tab of MobaXterm freezes. Can you please help me solve this issue? Thanks.

The version of MobaXterm is Personal Edition v23.2 Build 5082. It's running on Windows 10. The version of "tigervnc-standalone-server" installed in remote Ubuntu is "1.12.0+dfsg-4". All other software installed is most up-to-date.